# Reduce[] stuck and can't get results

Tags: equation-solving

I tried the following command:

```
Reduce[ {-K + 
    1/(1 + Exp[-\[Beta]*(B^(1/(1 + \[Delta]))*
            K^(\[Gamma]/(1 + \[Delta]) + \[Alpha] - 1)*(1 - 
               K)^(-\[Alpha])*(\[Alpha] - K) - C)]) == 0 , 
  B > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, \[Gamma] < 1, \[Delta] > 0, \[Delta] < 
   1, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Alpha] < 1, \[Beta] > 0, C > 0, K > 0, 
  K < 1}, K, Reals]
```

But couldn't get any results. I need at least to know how many admittable solutions there are. I tried also Solve obviously. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use capital letters for variables etc. `C`, and `K` have reserved built-in meanings.

Comment: Can't say there's a way to count them or reduce this, but you can find specific solutions using `FindInstance` like this: `FindInstance[{-k + 
    1/(1 + Exp[-β*(B^(1/(1 + δ))*
            k^(γ/(1 + δ) + α - 1)*(1 - 
               k)^(-α)*(α - k) - c)]) == 0, 
  B > 0, γ > 0, γ < 1, δ > 0, δ < 
   1, α > 0, α < 1, β > 0, c > 0, k > 0, k < 1},
 {B, γ, δ, α, β, c, k},
 Reals]` In fact ,`FindInstance` seems to be able to find a lot of solutions if you use the `RandomSeeding` technique: https://pastebin.com/63mUNa6F